# Function of pandas DataFrame that creates single value output

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a DataFrame made of boolean values. What I want is to check whether all entries are `True` by applying some function that simply outputs `True`or `False`after looking at each individual entry. Is there an easy or elegant way to do this?

And more generally speaking, say I have some DataFrame and I want to apply a function to the entries and output a single value (e.g. sum all the elements up, or take the product of all the elements). Is there some native way to create a function of the form

```
def f(df):
   return single_value(df)
```

I have seen plenty of methods that subject DataFrame entries to functions, but they all return a DataFrame (most of the time changing it in place). A mathematical example of what I want would be a vector norm since it maps vectors (series in pds) to positive real values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether the entire dataframe contains only `True` boolean values then all you need is

```
df.eq(True).all()
```

and the output will be a `Series` that indicates whether each column has `True` values. For instance,

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [True, True], 'col2': [True, False], 'col3': [True, None]})
>>> df.eq(True).all()
col1     True
col2    False
col3    False
dtype: bool
```

Now if you want the output to be a single boolean value then you can apply `all()` on the above:

```
>>> df.eq(True).all().all()
False
```

---

- [eq()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) can be used to perform element-wise comparisons
- [all()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) is used to check whether all elements are `True`, potentially over an axis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you elaborate a bit on how this works?